# predict the number of duracell bunnies playing a beat at the same time for any second

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose you have a steadily growing group of drummers (you may remember the Duracell bunnies) playing together.

The first drummer starts on second 1 and plays a beat every 1 seconds

The second drummer starts on second 2 and plays a beat every 2 seconds

The third drummer starts on second 3 and plays a beat every 3 seconds

...

The size of the group grows indefinitely, such that a drummer is added every second.

The nth drummer starts on second n and plays a beat every n seconds

On second 2, two bunnies play a beat simultaneously (1 and 2); on second 4, 3 bunnies play a beat simultaneously (1, 2, 4); etc.

Can anyone find a formula to calculate for any second n, how many bunnies play a beat at n? (e.g. if n is 10 million, how many bunnies play a beat on this second?);

Comment: They were Energizer bunnies, not Duracell.  Look at seconds $3,5,6,8,9,10$.   Maybe you will see a pattern.

Comment: ha - not quite: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duracell_Bunny

Comment: I think of the Engergizer campaign as much more memorable, as evidenced by my comment.

Comment: fair enough. However the question can't be resolved by looking at just the seconds you mention. I think I wasn't clear enough that a new drummer is added every second (now clarified).

Comment: I recognized that.  If you look at which bunnies drum at each of these seconds you might find a pattern that will extend upwards.  Maybe $10$ is the most useful case.  Which bunnies drum then?

Comment: You want the [number of divisors function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Definition), $\sigma_0(n)$ at the link, which unfortunately is a function of the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: In particular, ten million is $2^75^7$ so $(7+1)(7+1)=64$ bunnies. But ten million plus nineteen is prime, so for that value of $n$, just two bunnies.

Comment: Thanks Gerry, so we find the number of bunnies for any particular number by factorizing. But I'm looking for a formula to say what's the number of bunnies for any n that will beat on that second; or, alternatively, the largest number of bunnies that could be playing synchronously on that beat (a least upper bound on the factors?).

Comment: You might want to look at http://oeis.org/A002182 and the formulas and links and references given there.

Comment: Have you had a look at that link?

Comment: Are you still here, cath?